# Single for loop giving different result than many for loops

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am trying to learn programming and I wrote a code for adding items into ArrayList. There are many for loops and every loop is running for a specific interval and this give me correct result.
But rather than many for loops I tried just one for loop with IF Else statement and this doenots give me correct result
Please can anyone check and tell what is wrong?

```
  ArrayList dogs = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList cats = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList rabbits = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList guineaPigs = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList birds = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList ferrets = new ArrayList();

        //Before
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            dogs.Add(new Animal(240.00, "D-PUP" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            dogs.Add(new Animal(190.00, "D-JUN" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dogs.Add(new Animal(120.00, "D-ADU" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            dogs.Add(new Animal(60.50, "D-SEN" + i));
        }
        //Before            
        for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            cats.Add(new Animal(220.00, "C-KIT" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            cats.Add(new Animal(180.50, "C-JUN" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            cats.Add(new Animal(120.00, "C-ADU" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cats.Add(new Animal(50, "C-SEN" + i));
        }
        //Before            
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            rabbits.Add(new Animal(120.75, "R-KIT" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
        {
            rabbits.Add(new Animal(40.00, "R-ADU" + i));
        }
        //Before 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            guineaPigs.Add(new Animal(15.00, "G-PUP" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            guineaPigs.Add(new Animal(7.50, "G-ADU" + i));
        }
        //Before
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            birds.Add(new Animal(90.00, "B-CHI" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        { 
            birds.Add(new Animal(65.00, "B-ADU" + i));
        }           
        //Before
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            ferrets.Add(new Animal(150.00, "F-PUP" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            ferrets.Add(new Animal(120.00, "F-ADU" + i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            ferrets.Add(new Animal(30.50, "F-SEN" + i));
        }
        //After
        int j = 30;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
        {
            if(i < 1)
            {
                ferrets.Add(new Animal(150.00, "F-PUP" + i));
            }
            if(i < 2)
            {
                birds.Add(new Animal(90.00, "B-CHI" + i));
                ferrets.Add(new Animal(30.50, "F-SEN" + i));
            }
            if(i < 3)
            {
                ferrets.Add(new Animal(120.00, "F-ADU" + i));
            }
            if(i < 5)
            {
                dogs.Add(new Animal(60.50, "D-SEN" + i));
                guineaPigs.Add(new Animal(15.00, "G-PUP" + i));
                birds.Add(new Animal(65.00, "B-ADU" + i));
            }

            if(i < 10)
            {
                dogs.Add(new Animal(120.00, "D-ADU" + i));
                cats.Add(new Animal(50, "C-SEN" + i));
                guineaPigs.Add(new Animal(7.50, "G-ADU" + i));
            }
            if(i < 15)
            {
                dogs.Add(new Animal(190.00, "D-JUN" + i));
                cats.Add(new Animal(120.00, "C-ADU" + i));
                rabbits.Add(new Animal(120.75, "R-KIT" + i));
                rabbits.Add(new Animal(40.00, "R-ADU" + i));   
            }
            if(i < 20)
            {
                dogs.Add(new Animal(240.00, "D-PUP" + i));
            }
            if(i < 25)
            {
                cats.Add(new Animal(220.00, "C-KIT" + i));   
            }
            if(i < 30)
            {
                cats.Add(new Animal(180.50, "C-JUN" + i));
            }
        }
```

Comment: No didn't work!

Comment: ...btw. working with `ArrayList` in 2017 is... suboptimal. You might want to read up on [generics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms379564.aspx) and then use `List<Animal>` instead.

Comment: When you say the second way produces "incorrect" results, do you mean the result has the wrong number of items or do you mean the result has the correct number of items, but "in the wrong places"?

Comment: Sorry, took a while longer. As expected, both ways create *the exact same* items. The *difference* is the order of items. If you can live with that, great. If not, you might want to take a look at LINQs [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966.aspx). And definitely migrate away from `ArrayList` (and `Hashtable` for that matter...) to the generic and typesafe counterparts (`List<T>` and `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`).

Comment: Btw. if you create a `public enum AnimalType { Dog, Cat, Rabbit, GuineaPig, Bird, Ferret }` you could give your `Animal` class that type as a property. That way, you wouldn't need a separate list for each type, but could keep them all in *one* list and still be able to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a best way to write a code, because it confusing and, as you can see, makes things complex to understand. It's really complex to understand that you need 30 cats "C-JUN"

keep your first option with separate `for` loops, or Change to `dogs.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(i=>new Animal(240.00, "D-PUP" + i)))`

Comment: Cannot Convert from System.Generic.IEnumerable<Animal> to System.Collection.ICollection

Comment: Ensure you are using AddRange